# when Navigate the another page Need to add activity indicator

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uiactivityindicatorview, viewdidload

```
#import "LoginVC.h"
#import "HOMEVC.h"
#import "DashboardVC.h"
@interface LoginVC ()

@end

@implementation LoginVC
UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner ;
-(IBAction)login:(id)sender{

    NSString *userUpdate =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[Usernamefileld text]];
    NSString *userUpdate1 =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[PasswordField text]];
    NSString *baseURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://192.168.1.200:8094/YazakiService.svc/LOGIN/%@/%@",userUpdate,userUpdate1];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[baseURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *error;
    NSData *responseData =[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    NSMutableArray *serviceResponse=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
    NSLog(@"got response==%@", serviceResponse);
    NSDictionary *template=[serviceResponse objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *test=[template objectForKey:@"ValidState"];
    // NSString *test1=[template objectForKey:@"Userid"];
    NSString *helloString = @"1";
    //   //
    //   NSString *helloString1 =@"LFY430";
    if ([test isEqual:helloString]) {
        [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(threadStartAnimating:) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
        [self moveToView];

        //        UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Login Successfully" message:@"Correct Uername/Password" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

    }
    else{

        UIAlertView *alert2=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Login Failed" message:@"Incorrect Uername/Password" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];

        [alert2 show];
        [self alertView1:alert2 didDismissWithButtonIndex:alert2];

    }

}

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150, 225, 20, 30)];
    [spinner setActivityIndicatorViewStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    spinner.color = [UIColor blackColor];
    [self.view addSubview:spinner];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

-(void)moveToView{

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];


    DashboardVC *initView =  (DashboardVC*)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Dashboardvc"];

    [initView setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];

    [spinner stopAnimating];
    [self presentViewController:initView animated:NO completion:nil];
}


- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    [self moveToView];
}

- (void) alertView1:(UIAlertView *)alertView1 didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    LoginVC *initView =  (LoginVC*)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"loginvc"];
    [initView setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];
    [self presentViewController:initView animated:NO completion:nil];
}
-(void)threadStartAnimating:(id)data
{
    [spinner startAnimating];
}


@end
```

here by i initialse the indicator and start and stop the spinner but its not woking for me...
any one help me to solve the issues how to add the activity indicator when navigation the another view

Thanks in Advance

Comment: why u did the method call in wrong place

Comment: can u help me to fix the issues

Comment: but your code is synchronous method, how its works sister

Comment: ok what u tried , what the answer u need

Comment: i got from reference coding...how do i do that

Comment: u can check my post ...i need to add activator indicator when navigate to another view ..karthick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[self.view addSubview:spinner];
```

At this line you add the activity indicator to the current `ViewController` view.

However once you navigate to other view

```
DashboardVC *initView =  (DashboardVC*)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Dashboardvc"];
[self presentViewController:initView animated:NO completion:nil];
```

the current view changes to the new ViewController's view.
The activity indicator isnt present in that view and therefore you wont see your activity indicator there.

To solve, you should again add activity indicator in the second ViewController's `viewDidLoad` method
In Dashboard VC

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150, 225, 20, 30)];
    [spinner setActivityIndicatorViewStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    spinner.color = [UIColor blackColor];
    [self.view addSubview:spinner];
}
```

> A better solution would be to use third party progress huds which make
>   the loading indicator part absolutely easy like [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD)

Comment: Its Not Working for me Mr.Shubhank

Comment: we need to debug your code , can you drop by the (http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26424/iosandroidchaosoverflow)

Comment: i would still like to discuss more freely on the chat since there are still many questions i want to ask about your code. let me know when you can discuss on the chat

Answer (score 0):

When you stop `UIActivityIndicatorView` then also hide it.

`[spinner setHidesWhenStopped:YES];`

EDIT:
If you are not sure about `NSThread` then just do like this.

```
if ([test isEqual:helloString]) {
    //[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(threadStartAnimating:) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
    [spinner startAnimating];
    [self moveToView];

}
```

And when you want to stop it ten

```
[spinner stopAnimating];
[spinner setHidesWhenStopped:YES];
```

Comment: it not working for me the activity indicator not showing

Comment: -(void)threadStartAnimating:(id)data
{
    [spinner startAnimating];
}  spinner not evn start animating

Comment: where you are testing this condition `[test isEqual:helloString]` ? (in which method)

Comment: -(IBAction)login:(id)sender{
    NSString *userUpdate =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[Usernamefileld text]];
    NSString *userUpdate1 =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[PasswordField text]];  NSString *helloString = @"1";
    //   //
    //   NSString *helloString1 =@"LFY430";
    if ([test isEqual:helloString])

Comment: why are you using `NSThread `? Any specific reasons ? why don't you just put `[spinner startAnimating]`.

Comment: i got from the reference coding so i used here

Answer (score 0):

You should add activityindicator on `navigation controller` so, it is remains on front when you navigate.

you should use [MBProgressHud](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD) the great third party library.

Just put class in your project and import .h file in your class when you want to show activity indicator and then add HUD (activity indicator) like,

```
 [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
 // in your case show hud on `self.navigationController.view`
 // use main thread to show if required
```

and hide like,

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
// Do something...
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
});
 });
```

Hope this will help :)

Comment: i don't want to use third party library ...can u edit my code and suggest me the best and

Answer (score 0):

instead of using indicator , use svprogresshud.Check this link https://github.com/SVProgressHUD/SVProgressHUD.
if you want animated progressbar  check this link https://github.com/cemolcay/GiFHUD